# How do I make a function that checks if the images are the same and returns a result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a rock paper scissor game. I'm fairly new to javascript so I don't know a lot. I created a function already that displays the choice of the computer when the user makes a selection. What I'm trying to do next is make a function that compares the choice the user made and the choice the cpu made and then return a result, whether it's win, lose or draw.

I've tried to run an if statement to check if they're equal but i cant figure out how to check if the two images are equal to each other when the choices are made.

```js
let userRock = document.querySelector('.rock')
let userPaper = document.querySelector('.paper')
let userScissors = document.querySelector('.scissors')
const cpuScissors = document.querySelector('.cpu-scissors')
const cpuPaper = document.querySelector('.cpu-paper')
const cpuRock = document.querySelector('.cpu-rock')
let result = document.querySelector('.result')
let currentItem;

userPaper.addEventListener('click', start)
userScissors.addEventListener('click', cpuChoice)
userRock.addEventListener('click', cpuChoice)

function start() {
  cpuChoice()
  getWinner()
}

// Computer Choice
function cpuChoice() {
  const rand = Math.random()
  if (currentItem) {
    currentItem.style.display = 'none'
  }
  if (rand < .34) {
    cpuPaper.style.display = 'inline-block'
    currentItem = cpuPaper;
  } else if (rand >= .67) {
    cpuRock.style.display = 'inline-block'
    currentItem = cpuRock;

  } else {
    cpuScissors.style.display = 'inline-block'
    currentItem = cpuScissors;
  }
}

// Get Winner 
function getWinner() {

}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="score">
    <p>You:0</p>
    <p>Computer:0</p>
  </div>

  <div class="user-choice">
    <img class="rock" src="icons/rock.png">
    <img class="paper" src="icons/paper.png">
    <img class="scissors" src="icons/scissors.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cpu-result">
    <img class="cpu-rock" src="icons/rock.png">
    <img class="cpu-paper" src="icons/paper.png">
    <img class="cpu-scissors" src="icons/scissors.png">

  </div>

  <div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: This is an XY problem. You're asking how to check when two images are equal, when it would be much simpler to compare the user's input and the computer's choice. `if(userInput === cpuChoice)` would compare the variables directly, instead of comparing the _changes made to DOM elements according to the values of the variables_.

Comment: For instance, let's say the player chooses `1` and the computer chooses `2`. The logical thing to do is to compare `if(1 === 2)`. But what you are doing is, "Load image 1 in slot 1, and load image 2 in slot 2, and then write an instruction that fetches both images and compare them to see if the images are identical". You are trying to solve a very simple problem with a very complicated solution.

Comment: Yea I understand what you're saying but how would I convert those images so that they are recognize as 1 2 & 3 so then I could compare it to the computer choice

Comment: Well then, attach a load event listener to each image. Since loading is asynchronous, you need to wait for both images to load with a Promise. Then you have to initiate a local file reader, convert the images to Base64 strings, and compare of both strings are equal. _OR YOU CAN JUST DO `if(1===2)`_.

Comment: I want to do it the if (1 === 2) way but im having trouble doing that because i want to use those images, unless there is a way to set those images equal to number options , maybe im just not seeing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong in the way that :
- you make the player choose;
- you make the computer choose;
- you update the view (hiding/showing images);
- you then try to compare the images that are on display to determine who won.

The correct logic would be :
- make the player choose;
- make the computer choose;
- Compare both results to determine who won;
- Update the view (hide/show images).

What's on display is just a reflection of what's happening behind the scenes in the script.

I've put together in 10 minutes a little rock-paper-scissors game. There are probably more clever ways to find the winner, but you'll get the idea.

```js
const items = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"],
  issues = ["Draw", "You win", "Computer wins"];

let playerChoice = "",
  compChoice = "";

$("button").click(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  $("button").css("outline", "none");
  $this.css("outline", "blue solid 2px");
  playerChoice = $this.data("val");
  computerChooses();
})

const computerChooses = () => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // 0,1 or 2
  compChoice = items[rand]; // "rock", "paper" or "scissors"
  $(".compChoice img").hide();
  $(".compChoice").show();
  $("#img" + rand).show();
  findWinner()
}

const findWinner = () => {
  let issue;

  if (playerChoice === compChoice) {
    issue = 0;
  } else if (playerChoice === "rock") {
    issue = compChoice === "scissors" ? 1 : 2;
  } else if (playerChoice === "paper") {
    issue = compChoice === "scissors" ? 2 : 1;
  } else { // player chose scissors
    issue = compChoice === "rock" ? 2 : 1;
  }
  $(".result").text(issues[issue]) // "Draw", "You win" or "Computer wins"
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.compChoice {
  display: none;
}

.compChoice img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Choose :</div>

<button data-val="rock">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/838/838023.svg"/>
</button>

<button data-val="paper">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/sheet-of-paper.png"/>
</button>

<button data-val="scissors">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/scissors/win8/1600"/></button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="compChoice">
  <div>Computer picks :</div><img id="img0" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/838/838023.svg" /><img id="img1" src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/1600/sheet-of-paper.png" /><img id="img2" src="https://png.icons8.com/scissors/win8/1600" />
</div>
<br/>
<div class="result"></div>
```